# .NET: Why has the unsafe option be made irrelevant?

Tags: .net, .net-core, clr, coreclr

I just realized that there now is `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`. You can create a console application, write

```
Unsafe.AddByteOffset(ref (new int[1])[0], (IntPtr)Int32.MaxValue) = 42;
```

and you get a `System.AccessViolationException`.

Compiled without `/unsafe`, no `fixed` or `unsafe` blocks, just like that. With both net472 and netcore.

I would have thought that unless I explicitly tell the compiler I want to do unsafe stuff, memory violations are an impossibility (safe bugs in the runtime).

So when was that guarantee lost and what replaced it?

Also, why make an assembly that just allows you to do what you could do with `unsafe` blocks and pointers anyway? Such an assembly wouldn't pass PEverify, and rightly so. Now the state of affairs is that any assembly that is cleared by PEverify can still use `Unsafe` and be totally unsafe in practice, right? Smells weird.

Comment: At least _some_ of the stuff you cannot even do with an `unsafe` block, but need to write IL. Hence, that is what `Unsafe` is [implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.il) in.

Comment: The `unsafe` keyword applies to C# syntax (pointers, stackalloc), not to framework classes.   The class name leaves few guesses.  Not the only way to do unsafe things, attributes like [StructLayout.Explicit] can cause plenty of havoc.

Comment: @HansPassant While I didn't know that about `StructLayout` and do find it also surprising, PEverify is going to catch that. I makes the assembly unverifiable. It used to be guaranteed that an app domain can't hack another app domain when the assembly is verifiable (and assuming the system libraries are bug-free). That's no longer the case.